# Dataset '{}' does not exist or is not supported in arcpy

Tags: arcpy, parameters, error-000732, string, python-3

I am trying to insert some variable into a simple `arcpy` call using `.format(var1, var2)` as I would in a string. I am new to using Python 3.6, so maybe there's been some change in how this is done. When I run the following, I get a

> ERROR 000732: Layer Name or Table View: Dataset '{}' does not exist or is not supported

error, which then causes an Execute Error for bad parameters. What am I doing wrong here?

```
  select = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("'{}'", "NEW_SELECTION", "FIPS_CODE = '{}'").format(name, item)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should try this instead:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("{}".format(name), "NEW_SELECTION", "FIPS_CODE = '{}'".format(item))
```

If it works, I can explain what you did wrong.

If it does not, then I suggest expanding your code snippet to `print` variables `name` and `item`, before you try to use them.